# Replacing all elements except last in specific rows of 2D Array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently working on a classification task and stumbled upon a problem:

I've got an 2D array A (1000 x 441) (the last element is the label for classification) and some error values E (shape 1000 x 440).

What I'm trying to do is to substract or add the error values from my input array depending on the label.

Why can't I simply do

```
add = [1,2,3,4] # just some random indices
sub = [6,7,8,9]
A[add][:,:-1] += E[add]
A[sub][:,:-1] -= E[sub]
```

There are no changes happening in A. Not sure why this is happening.
i.e is working:

```
A[0][:-1] += E[0] # this works
```

It works using a simple for loop but I want to avoid iterating over every vector in my data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The submitted answer is good, also you can make a view first to avoid code duplication `tmp=A[:,:-1];A[add]+=E[add];A[sub]-=E[sub]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the indexing all in one go:

```
A[add,:-1] += E[add]
```

Otherwise, the "fancy indexing" of `A[add]` produces a copy, which when modified does not affect `A`.